# Composer config: use ~tilde instead of ^caret for new requires

Tags: php, composer-php, semantic-versioning

Is it possible to configure PHP Composer to use a `~` prefix to constrain dependencies to patch-level updates (like 1.2.x) instead of the default `^` (1.x.x)?

The term used in their documentation is "[Next Significant Release Operators](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#next-significant-release-operators)," but I don't see any related options in their config

(NPM has similar behavior but you can configure it in your .npmrc file with `save-prefix=~`. My rationale is that our build system can't trust every package author to use semantic versioning correctly, or at all.

Comment: How are you adding your requires? If you specify a version using `~` (e.g. `composer require foo/bar ~1.2`) your `composer.json` file should reflect that same constraint.

Comment: I meant if I just say composer require some/package and press enter to use the latest version, it will update composer.json with ^latest by default. Maybe it's not the typical use case, but I rarely know what the latest version of a package is when I pull it in, so I almost always just hit enter to use the latest.